# passing a value to a method and then printing it

Tags: java

i came across this question in an interview.

```
public class NuVizzDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int x=6;
        System.out.println("initial value of x is "+x);
        int y=getX(x);
        System.out.println("value of x after method is executed is "+x);
        System.out.println("value of y is "+y);
    }

    private static int getX(int x) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(x==1){
            System.out.println("value of X is "+x);
            return 0;
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("value of x is "+x);
            return 1+getX(x-1);
    }

}
```

I want to know how come value of `y` is `1` less than `x`?

Comment: What did you answer in the interview?

Comment: I don't really want to answer the question since it will spoil the interviewer's effort to come up with the question . But you could run the code and see why that happens.

Comment: Side note: you don't have braces around your `else` clause. It won't affect the result, but it does mean the indentation is sort of lying.

Comment: You found an interview question with `// TODO Auto-generated method stub` !?

Comment: If you step through the code using your debugger, you should be able to see what it is doing.

Comment: i said 6..and i lost the interview. i tried run that code on my computer so is that //TODO .

Answer (score 7):

Because the function `getX` is [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) and follows this pattern:

```
x = 1: 0
x = 2: 1 + getX(1) = 1 + 0 = 1
x = 3: 1 + getX(2) = 1 + 1 + getX(1) = 1 + 1 + 0 = 2
...
```

**Edit:** You should make `getX` more robust by adding a clause for `x <= 0`. For such a value of `x` your code will throw a `StackOverflowError` (which is a Good Thing™ for a question posted on Stack Overflow ☺).

Comment: plus 1, A slow way of subtracting `1` or if you give it `0` you get a StackOverflowError ;)

Comment: Yes, that's why I've skipped the 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

Because

`return 1+getX(x-1);`

will give you the value `1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 5`  since when `x` reaches to the `1` you are expicitly returning `0`.

Answer (score 0):

So this recursive call will go for 5 times and at the 5th time the returned value will be 0, because it will return 0 when `x == 1`.

So when:

```
x = 1 -> 0
x = 2 -> 0 + 1 = 1
x = 3 -> 1 + 1 + getX(1) = 2
x = 4 -> 1 + 1 + 1 + getX(1) = 3
x = 5 -> 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + getX(1) = 4
x = 6 -> 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + getX(1) = 5
```

So it's y = 5.